# Using Join Query in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not able to fetch data with this Query. It works fine I try to execute it directly on table through SQLManager. Here is my code:
 In DatabaseAdapter class:

```
protected Cursor fetchCustomerInfo() {
    String Query = "SELECT  " 
                    + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_NAME 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_CONTACT 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_EMAIL 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_PRIORITY_ID
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE_ID 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.ITEM_SERIAL
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.PICKUPITEM_ID 
                    + " FROM " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE 
                    + " INNER JOIN " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE 
                    + " ON " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE 
                    + " = "+ DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE;  
    Log.i("Join Customer and item", Query);
    return database.rawQuery(Query, null);
}
```

In DatabaseController class:

```
public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> fetchCustomerInfo(Context context) {

    DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<CustomerInfo> model = new ArrayList<CustomerInfo>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(context).open();
        cursor = dbAdapter.fetchCustomerInfo();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_NAME));
                String contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_CONTACT));
                String customerAddress = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS));
                String customerEmail = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_EMAIL));
                int pickupPriorityId =  cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_PRIORITY_ID));
                String itemType = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE));
                String itemSerial = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.ITEM_SERIAL));
                int itemTypeId = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE_ID));
                int pickupItemId = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.PICKUPITEM_ID));
                int customerAcc = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE));
                CustomerInfo customer = new CustomerInfo(name, contactNumber, customerAddress, customerEmail, pickupPriorityId, itemType, itemSerial, itemTypeId, pickupItemId, customerAcc);
                model.add(customer);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        dbAdapter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            cursor.close();
            dbAdapter.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }
    }
    return model;
```

}

And calling it by:

```
    allCustomerArraylist = dbController.fetchCustomerInfo(rootView.getContext());
```

Shows error:

```
     Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 9 columns.
```

Comment: paste the log which you get when you hit this query from  your app.

Comment: What are the result column names in SQLManager?

Comment: When I run it through sqlmanager it gives desired answer. But here arraylist is blank

Comment: @CL. With delete query we must use db.execQuery or db.rawQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the field DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE as well if you want to access its value later.

So this should work:

```
protected Cursor fetchCustomerInfo() {
    String Query = "SELECT  " 
                    + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_NAME 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_CONTACT 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_EMAIL 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_PRIORITY_ID
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE_ID 
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.ITEM_SERIAL
                    + ", " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.PICKUPITEM_ID 
                    + " FROM " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE 
                    + " INNER JOIN " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE 
                    + " ON " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE 
                    + " = "+ DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE;  
    Log.i("Join Customer and item", Query);
    return database.rawQuery(Query, null);
}
```